# how to declare matriz[3][3] or [2][2] in Z3 using SMT

Tags: z3

I need write a `matrix[n][n]` in smt using Z3opt, but I did not find in the rise4fun Guide.

I use Z3opt site to write my code. I can't use c/c++/.net, only smt.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix dimensions `n`x`n` are statically known, you could simply introduce a symbol `M_i_j` per matrix element. It will probably make sense to automatically generate the corresponding SMT code, e.g. via some script.